# How to get around iframe? links that go outside my wordpress website won't open

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, iframe

I am kinda new in web development , i made a wordpress site , placed a link to twitter in the menu bar and it wont work . I checked the chrome console and it gives me the error "*Refused to display 'https://twitter.com/Euthimis_K' in a frame because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self'".* " . I know there is a problem with iframe but i don't really know (or have found yet) how to solve this..? Or is there a way to make links open in a new window (maybe this will fix it?) .

Thanks!

Comment: Are you a wordpress user or a programmer? As a user check this: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16758/make-menu-items-open-in-new-tab-page

Comment: mostly a user but i want to get into the code of WordPress

Comment: It works ! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, you can add target="_blank" to your  tag for links.